# Update text field with TinyMce Content on submit

Tags: jquery, tinymce

Ive added the TinyMCE editor to a 'dynamic' form that receives an item to update and updates the item div with the text one enters into TinyMce. This works fine and updates the div. 
My save function uses the text from the div and not tinymce. 
My problem is that when using any of the formatting functions i.e. H2, unless you hit enter, the div does not get updated.

any ideas?

here is my code:

```
setup : function(ed) {
ed.onKeyUp.add(function(ed, e) {
  var articlebody = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent({format : 'raw'});                    
  $("#article_body").html(articlebody);                       
}
```

Comment: not sure what you're realy asking? what is you exact goal here?

Comment: how do I get TinyMce to update using jquery i.e. click the mce box to initialise it...

Comment: please explain a bit more what you do and what the result is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when the end user changes the format (like adding a H2) that's not going to trigger the "*keyUp*" event you use to update your "*#article_body*" div with.

You could use the [onChange](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3aevent.tinymce.Editor.onChange) event as this fires when an undo level is added and should cover not only new content, but also formatting changes.